# Difference between sql agent account logged in as NTLM and UPN?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

Can someone please tell the difference between a sql agent account logged in as NTLM and UPN?

What is the difference if the sql agent account is logged in as:
`domain\username` and `username@domain.com`?

In what way will the functionality affect and where?
Would it affect 'execute as' statements in sql stored procedures?

Comment: Do you mean `username@domain`? I remember there was a difference at my previous job many years ago, and I remember we had to standardize on one, but I'm sorry I forget which or why.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know that it depends on how we add the account to the logon tab of the service. If we browse for the account when adding it to the service we get the UPN form.If we manually type in the account name we can use either one. For your question...I mean domain\username. But I would like to know in what way does either one make a difference in the functionality elsewhere in sql server.

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify what I meant. You listed `username.abc.de.org` which I think you meant `username@abc.de.org`. Anyway my best recollection is that one of those forms did *not* work when trying to grant the service account permissions to other resources in the network outside of the SQL Server machine (I think it was a particular file share that was problematic), and I think it was with mixed servers (e.g. Windows Server 2000, 2003, 2003 R2, etc).

Comment: Sorry...You are right, I meant username@abc.de.org..Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Servers do not allow the use of User Principle Name (UPN) addresses for service accounts.  There is a post from a few years ago in Microsoft Connect and a more recent post:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/519008/upn-user-principal-name-as-services-account-name#details

http://www.ryanjadams.com/2014/02/error-authenticating-proxy-sql-and-upns/#axzz2x0igTI3n

Therefore you need to stick with the DOMAIN\USERNAME format for the service accounts.

(Original post failed to commit.  Repost.)